# With Rails 5, how to left joins with selected associations and order by association count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, left-join, ruby-on-rails-5

here are my models:

```
class Article
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now I am trying to order the articles, by the count of votes in the past 24 hours. Any suggestions for how to do this?

I have tried this:

```
Article.left_joins(:votes).group("articles.id").order("count(votes.id) DESC")
```

However, this is ordering by all the votes, not the votes in last 24h. Any suggestions?

One more thing is, I still need to get the articles with no votes. So I am not sure how to use the where clause here...

Comment: `where('votes.created_at >= ?', 1.day.ago)` ? or similar (may need to check the direction of the `<`)

Comment: I don't think that will works because it will miss the articles with no votes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it work. It turns out left_joins is not necessary. My current solution is using select clause in the order() function:

```
Article.order("(select count(*) from votes where votes.article_id = articles.id and votes.created_at >= NOW() - '1 day'::INTERVAL ) desc")
```

Maybe not elegant, but works well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the date when the vote was created for an article prior to the count of votes in your order.

Try this:

```
Article.left_joins(:votes)
       .group("articles.id")
       .order("DATE(votes.created_at) DESC, count(votes.id) DESC")
```

Then if you only want to get the articles that has been upvoted for the past 24hr, you can chain this to your query:

```
.where("votes.created_at >= ?", 1.day.ago)
```

Comment: I am getting this error with the code: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "votes.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function